# How to get absolute coordinates with QGraphicsScene?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

Let's say I have five objects, with the top-left red square and the larger black square both inserted into the scene at 0,0.

[image: A central object with 4 red smaller objects.]
 .

Later, let's say I want to move the bottom right corner of the black square to the bottom right corner of the bottom-right square. The most obvious thing to do would be:

bS.setRect( bS.rect().setBottomRight(redBR.rect().bottomRight) );

That's not exactly correct code, but the idea is simple. I would set the coordinate of the black square's bottom right corner to that of the red square's bottom right corner. *Because that's where I want it to be.* But in Qt, this seems to be impossible.

Because the call to redBR thinks it's at the origin. *Every item thinks it's at the origin.* Which means I can never know the coordinates of any item, anywhere, ever.

Is there a way to force QGraphicsScene to tell me the actual coordinates? **Alternatively, is there some other graphics framework that uses real coordinates?** I'm not going to insist on using Qt if there is no way to make it work.

Any help would be welcome. Please bear in mind my goal is not: "drag corner of box by manipulator". My goal is to be able to put items at coordinates whenever I want an item to be at a specific coordinate.

### Edit:

---

Here's an example of what I mean. The big box hasn't been connected yet, so don't worry about it's coordinates. The problem is that if I *don't* remap the points coming out of the little box, every box believes it is at the origin. But if I *do*, then the y values vacillate between 0, 1, and -1.

[image]

Comment: Could you please give another picture that represent the result of what you want? sometime like before and after.

Comment: I edited my post with a new picture, that shows both the raw pos values, and the value after calling mapFromScene or mapFromParent on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class `QGraphicsItem` has quite some useful functionality for mapping between scene and item coordinates. One useful function is for mapping a point in item coordinates to scene coordinates:

`QPointF QGraphicsItem::mapToScene(const QPointF &point)`

There is however also a direct mapping available between points in different `QGraphicsItem`s, which is probably the easiest to use here:

`QPointF QGraphicsItem::mapFromItem(const QGraphicsItem *item, const QPointF &point)`

which can be used to map a point in redBR to a point in bS like:

bS.rect().setBottomRight(bS.mapFromItem( &redBR, redBR.rect().bottomRight() ) )

Comment: I think your answer is correct in relation to the question I actually asked. I think I asked the wrong question though. My real problem was that I was creating the little boxes with coordinates, instead of creating *then* setting pos. So, because of API weirdness, they **really were** all at the origin.